# Typed associations in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a question regarding associations in MS Entity Framework 4: Is it possible to have typed many-to-many associations?

For example, imagine a set of people and a set of projects. What I would like to model now is the peoples association to the different projects, typed by the role they play in this project.

Is this possible with EF4, or do I have to model it by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must model it by hand. There can be some workaround with inheritance but I don't expect that your person always plays the same role in all projects so it would probably not work. Another way is using multiple many-to-many associations so that each role has its own association.

By model it by hand I meant exposing junction table as separate entity wich will include reference to person, project and role. This will happen automatically if you have it defined this way in database.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Since I don't know which types will be needed during runtime, I will model it by hand.

Comment: Thank's again, I will do it this way :)